# Laravel not returning join query to blade

Tags: laravel, pivot-table, laravel-blade

I have two queries, one is lighter on data by using the pivot table as a filter to get data from the main table (student in this case).

```
$students=\DB::table('student')->join('school_student', 'student.id', '=','school_student.student_id')->get();
```

This returns a query result from the controller.  But will not load into the blade:

```
$this->layout->content=\View::make('admin.students.index')->with('student', $students);
```

Whereas this versions returns a similar more data heavy (i.e. outputs all school data each time)
but works in blade.

```
$students = \Student::with(array('schools' => function($query){$query->where('school_id', '=', 1);}))->get();
```

Is it simply that DB and view are incompatible? 
If so what is the Laravel 4 method to query one table and it's pivot only.

Any help appreciated.

In the blade

```
@if($student->count())
```

The first example produces this error:

```
Call to a member function count() on a non-object
```

Comment: So if you `var_dump($student);` after both queries they both contain the same structure and data?

Comment: When you say "But will not load into the blade" does that mean your view becomes empty, or it throws error? Those two ways to fetch students are not equivalent, the first one you use does not use models and relationships, while the second one does. Please post the code of your blade template so we can explain a bit more.

Comment: I have added the blade issue. @Jeemusu The second(not working) produces a much larger array but the issue is the array not passing.@unnawut posted the blade part. Is there a way to use models without the extra data? Is not using models issue for parameters to blade?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`DB::...->get()` returns an array, so you can't call `->count()` on it (hence "non-object"), but instead you need `count($students)`.

The reason `->count()` works when you do the 'more data heavy' method is that you're using Eloquent and it returns Eloquent `Collection`s.

So, basically, you're doing two different things and expecting to treat them the same.

---

Also, while I'm here I should point out that I think your Eloquent query isn't quite right. First off you're hardcoding the id as 1 (whereas in the DB-style query you don't care about the school ID, and you just use it to join to the pivot table - maybe you used an incomplete query), but also you're using `with` but you should probably look at `has`. `with` eager-loads models, but `has` is what you want if you just want to check for a condition on a join table.

Comment: Thanks.So the non-Eloquent model remains more efficient though?

Comment: I guess it depends on your definition of efficient, but yes usually it will be as *you* get to control the query better (depending on what you want you should pass the columns you want to retrieve to the `->get()` call if you're serious about efficiency, as doing a `->get(0` still gets all columns for your array), and it only returns lightweight arrays rather than heavier objects. Also, I think your Eloquent line has a bit of a flaw - you have the right idea, but instead of doing a `has` you're doing a `with`, which actually performs the join and eager-loads the `School` model.

Comment: Np - I've added the bit about with/has to the answer. But yeah, you should check out [Eloquent's has method](http://laravel.com/docs/eloquent#querying-relations) as it's quite useful for your purposes. And might I just add that while the DB way is probably going to be more efficient, as long as you don't have a huge (100s of MiBs at least if not GiBs) database and a load of daily hits, maybe this kinda stuff is premature optimisation, and sometimes more descriptive (though less efficient) code is preferable for maintainability. Just a thought.